# Rails: Ambiguous tables in join for scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I am using plenty scoped searchs in my Rails app (Rails 4) and have got stuck on this issue where I have to use a join clause.

I have a class Company which has many Employees. Each Employee has a WorkId (1 through 5).

Edit (2015-11-29): The relation between Company and Employees is habtm through a "`company_employee_relations`"-table consisting of `company_id` and `employee_id`

I need a scoped search where I search:

Companies with at least 5 Employees having a WorkID=1

I have managed to do this to some extent with:

```
scope :has_several_active_employees, -> { where(:id => (Company.joins(:employees).group("companies.id").having("count(employees.work_id = 1) > 4")).collect(&:id)) }
```

This brings out the correct solution BUT causes several ambiguous style issues down the line when I try to match it with scopes like:

```
scope :is_active, -> { where(:active => true) }
```

this way

```
Company.is_active.has_several_active_employees
```

In addition, this doesn't seem to be a very elegant solution and it is VERY slow.

What I would need is to "step in into a joins clause and then step out again" so I can chain link these scopes without ending up with ambiguous issues down the line.

Edit: I should mention as well that altering "`is_active`" is not a viable option since I have several uses like this down the line. Basically, the problem needs to be addressed at the source, i.e. in the "`has_several_active_employees`" scope, so that it will not break either in other scopes or in views etc.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you're willing to have that kind of hand-coded SQL fragment in the system then your scope might as well be:

```
scope :has_several_active_employees, -> { where("(select count(employees.work_id = 1) from company_employee_relations r join employees e on r.employee_id = e.id where r.company_id = companies.id ) > 4")
```

... or ...

```
scope :has_several_active_employees, -> { where(:id => CompanyEmployeeRelation.joins(:employee).references(:employee).where(:employees => {:work_id => 1}).group(:company_id).having("count(*) > 4").pluck(:company_id))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the right path to go. I forgot to mention the crucial information that employee and company has a habtm-relationship through a "company_employee_relation"-table. That makes this solution not work. I have added that info to the question now. Sorry about that.

Comment: This was my former solution (that did not take work_id into consideration): scope :has_many_employees, -> { where(%q{(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company_employee_relations r WHERE r.company_id = companies.id) > 9 })}

Comment: @Christoffer Well I think that simply including the intermediate table in either of those queries would work fine.

Comment: thanks again. I don't really understand what you mean by this (tried a couple of ways), could you please update your answer to accomodate this?

Comment: I had a stab at it -- may be typos in there though.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `is_active` scope to..

```
scope :is_active, -> { where('companies.active = 1') }
```

This will avoid ambiguity when you merge scopes.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't clear enough in my description of the issue that this doesn't work for me. I mean, it solves the symptom, but just temporary since the problem continue to exist and cause ambiguous-stye problems for other scopes and usages of the Company-model down the line. I have added that information in my question now.